# Howto enable lock usage in MongoDB 3.2.8 - Failed: server does not support reporting lock information

Tags: mongodb, locking, database-performance

From [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongotop/)

> To report the use of per-database locks, use --locks
>
> Changed in version 3.0.0: When called against a mongod that does not
>   report lock usage, --locks will return a Failed: Server does not
>   support reporting locking information error

I receive this error

```
mongotop -vvv --host localhost --authenticationDatabase admin -u $USER -p $PASSWD  --port 27100 --locks
2016-08-29T14:29:41.477+0200    Failed: server does not support reporting lock information
```

Howto enable lock usage in MongoDB 3.2.8? Do I need a special startup parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. --locks option is used to report per-database locks. 
Starting from MongoDB 3.0 (for most operations) there are collection-level locks on MMAPv1 storage engine and document-level for wiredTiger and MongoRocks. You can find more info about concurrency here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/

Option --locks is useful only for MongoDB 2.x